# root CA , intermediate certificate and web server certificate in HTTPS communication

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, digital-signature

As you know, when we want to start a communication with a webserver using SSL protocol, after the first request to the webserver, it returns its certificate to us (we are the client.). Root CA certificates are loaded into our web browser and the browser use them to verify the incoming certificate (Incoming certificate is signed using Root CA private key at the time of creation.)

Well, what's the question?

What happens when the webserver certificate is not signed with the root CA and it is signed with an intermediate certificate that I don't have it in my browser? Am I need to download that intermediate certificate manually from somewhere and import it in my browser? Or the webserver itself return all the certificates that I need to verify its certificate?

Example:

[image]

Let assume that I send a request to a webserver that has number 1 as its certificate. The number 3 is loaded in my browser already but I don't have the number 2. In this situation, what happens when I send my request to the webserver?

Comment: The webserver should send the intermediate certificate(s) along with it's own certificate.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK "CA" certs whether root/intermediate must be present in the browser. If you have missing intermediate CA cert then you need to import to the browser. In the past I faced few exception related to this (in the intranet application) and once I import the missing certs the problem went away.

Comment: _once I import the missing certs the problem went away._ Do you mean that the webserver (the intranet server that you wanted to communicate with) didn't sent the intermediate certs along with its cert? Didn't those certs was  self-signed? Because for the self-signed certs I think it it more secure to force the user import them manually and not automatically by the webserver.

Comment: The intermediate in my case where CA from a vendor not self signed. If the intermediate CA in your case is self-signed then yes users have to manually import the cert - The web server do not send the CA certs but the CA details.